# Access Processes remotely .net

Tags: .net, process, ip

I have a list of computers which we can access them via IP address. I need to create a function where through this IP address I am able to get the version number of a specific process (e.g.  vb.exe). Check if this version number is valid, if not I force close this process, ALWAYS REMOTELY. Is this even possible to do so?

Comment: If you can deploy some binaries on the remote computer, you can use PsTools or a service with a remote interface (like wcf).

Comment: Process.GetProcesses comes to my mind, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx